# A VALID FILE NAME MUST BE SELECTED. [MULTIPLE FLAT FLILES CONNECTION MANAGER EDITOR] IN SSIS 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, flat-file

i.stack.imgur.com / HIj9H.png

As the image shows,  I am trying to have multiple flat files uploaded from a certain folder.

I have followed instructions from this site http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/RakeshMishra/sql-server-bi/323/sql-server-import-multiple-files-in-ssis-using-multi-flat-file

and many others but it seems to be having problems.

Does anyone know why it's not taking my wildcard?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put all relevant information in the question rather than referencing via an external link. Also, try not to use BLOCK CAPITALS as on the internet that is considered shouting, and potentially a bit rude.

Comment: Link is not working ... what error message your are getting, where it's getting..what package does...... provide more details....

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HIj9H.png

Comment: that's the link with the image of my multiple flat files connection manager